# Java PriorityQueue and Comparator Not Ordering correctly

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am new to Java and am trying to implement a priority queue with a custom comparator. I want to put the Sentences in the queue and have them removed in order to highest score.

For the comparator class I have:

```
public class SentenceScoreComparator implements Comparator<Sentence> {

@Override
public int compare(Sentence o1, Sentence o2) {
    if (o2.getScore() > o1.getScore()) return -1;
//fixed typo
    if (o2.getScore()  < o1.getScore()) return 1;
    return 0;
}

}
```

I then print out the sentences like so:

```
PriorityQueue<Sentence> allSentences = new PriorityQueue<Sentence>(new SentenceScoreComparator());
//add sentences

for(Sentence s :allSentences){
            System.out.println(s.getScore()); 
        }
```

but they are not in order

```
0.34432960587450223
0.47885099912108975
0.10991840331015199
0.36222267254836954
0.05164923572003221
0.5366117828694823
0.3891453014131773
0.0961512261934429
0.5566040852233918
0.5079687049927742
0.7628021620154812
0.6023121606121791
0.25695632228681914
0.15701049878801304
0.1260031244674359
0.36516025683986736
0.3846995962155155
```

I checked that the queue is using the comparator with the correct comparator method. Can someone explain what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the comparator in the second `if` where `o2` score is compared to itself.

Replace it with:

```
@Override
public int compare(Sentence o1, Sentence o2) {
    return Double.compare(o1.getScore(), o2.getScore());
}
```

On top of that, as bradimus answered, `PriorityQueue` does not guarantee any sorted traversal. Use a regular list and sort it for that.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that

Answer (score 3):

`PriorityQueue` never promised to traverse them in order. From the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> This class and its iterator implement all of the optional methods of the Collection and Iterator interfaces. The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).